# How to plot multiple types of plots onto a single chart in python?

Tags: python, visualization, data-analysis

I am trying to plot the data into something like this:
[image]

The data I'm using is in this form:

```
Date             GHI        PR
2019/07/01  3.256608333 69.57567588
2019/07/02  3.976766667 79.31441128
2019/07/03  2.811866667 61.02000579
2019/07/04  3.658408333 83.26257616
2019/07/05  5.590683333 82.12444039
2019/07/06  5.179733333 82.76417228
2019/07/07  4.120733333 69.92450703
2019/07/08  5.707991667 84.78915116
2019/07/09  6.469825    79.15239303
```

Here is the [link](https://cleantechenergycorp.sharepoint.com/sites/CleantechPublicLibrary/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2FCleantechPublicLibrary%2FShared%20Documents%2FIntern%20Selection%20Task%20-%20O%26M%20IT%2FAssignment_Task%2Epdf&parent=%2Fsites%2FCleantechPublicLibrary%2FShared%20Documents%2FIntern%20Selection%20Task%20-%20O%26M%20IT&p=true&ga=1)

I want to achieve this using python. I have already tried out and Im not able to do it.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 6))
plt.scatter('Date', 'PR', data=l2, label="<2", marker='o')
plt.scatter('Date', 'PR', data=g2l4, label="2~4", marker='D')
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[My Full code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w9aub2Wi-WDY-Xp37bOOn37-V_HdPzlO/view?usp=sharing)